# What happens to a variable assignment when I call a method that returns an instance of a case class holding the said variable?

Tags: scala, oop, functional-programming

During a recent interview I had with a fairly reputable software company, I was tripped up trying to provide a valid explanation to a seemingly trivial Scala question. Consider the following:

```
case class Person(var age: Int)
def person = new Person(10)
person.age = 3
println(person)
```

This is what is returned by the `println` statement:

```
Person(10)
```

The question is why is this and what is happening when I assign `3` to `person.age`?

Comment: The best answer probably was: "just don't use vars in a case class".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well,

```
def person = new Person(10)
```

is a function. That is, every time you call `person`, you create a new instance of `Person`. Thus, if we inline the function, your code would look like:

```
Person(10).age = 3
println(Person(10))
```

If you want to change the age of the person instance you created first, you need to capture that instance.

```
val p = person
p.age = 3
println(p)
```

Answer (score 9):

For this you need to understand the difference between `val` and `def`.

When you use `def` for any expression, it is evaluated every time it is being used. So, in this case when you do a `person.age = 3` It will create a new instance of person object and assign 3 to its age, and when you do `println(person)` it will again instantiate a new person class and hence it prints `Person(10)`.

So, If you have `val` instead of `def` like this: `val person = new Person(10)` and do

```
person.age = 3
println(person)
```

the output will be: `Person(3)` because, `val` is evaluated once. So, there will be only one instance of `person` in this case no matter how may times you use `person`.